# perl mojolicious - using flash gives wierd error

Tags: perl, mojolicious, flash-message

The below code is giving the error:

Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Mojolicious/Controller.pm line 286.

and I am not particularly sure how i'd go about handling it. Especially as it quotes an error in the source code that seems to be related to encryption of cookies. And my application contains no cookies or encryption so that is suprising.

```
 sub remove {
    my $self = shift;
    my $host_id = $self->stash('host_id');

    $self->hosts->remove($self->stash('host')->{host_id});

    $self->flash(message => 'User created successfully!');
    $self->redirect_to('hosts');
}
```

Comment: It might be implementing the flash message using a cookie. I'd have to read the source. Is there a variable that is being used as an array ref in line 286 of that file? Make sure you check the correct version of Mojo if you look via metacpan though.

Comment: Out of the box, Mojolicious sends a [session cookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious#sessions). It stores session data on the client side: *Persistent data storage for the next few requests, all session data gets serialized with Mojo::JSON and stored Base64 encoded in HMAC-SHA1 signed cookies, to prevent tampering. Note that cookies usually have a 4096 byte (4KB) limit, depending on browser.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely happens when you have `undef` as your secrets. The error comes from the [following line](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/334e72b968faa4427e82677793c31e303e0a88e3/lib/Mojolicious/Controller.pm#L286):

```
my $checksum = Mojo::Util::hmac_sha1_sum($value, $self->app->secrets->[0]);
```

Normally, the secret is pre-generated which is insecure and needs to be defined by you in the config of the app. An example of it being used is in the [Mojo::Pg example application](https://github.com/kraih/mojo-pg/tree/master/examples/blog):

```
{
    pg      => 'postgresql://tester:testing@/test',
    secrets => ['s3cret']
}
```

Which is then consumed by the application itself

```
$self->secrets($self->config('secrets'));
```

If your application sets the secrets from a config file but the config file doesn't declare a secrets, or the key has been misspelt, the error you write will be given back whenever you try to set a cookie, such as using the flash.